# Eclipse for Java giving console error when run project with arguments

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven, run-configuration

I am using Mac Big Sur and trying to run a project using arguments in the run config, but I get an error

> Sep 28, 2021 9:02:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap main
> WARNING: Bootstrap: command "testpass" does not exist.

The arguments which I am giving are shown below and the reference image also

```
/path/to/csvFile
empty
<jdbc string>
username
testpass
```

Instead of taking the "testpass" as an argument, it is taking as a command.

[image]

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The arguments section is just passed to the program you are running, this is not an Eclipse message

Comment: Why are you trying to pass these arguments to Tomcat? That does not make sense to me.